# How to run logstash from exploded jar with JRuby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jruby, logstash

I'm not very comfortable with `jruby` and `rvm` environments, so I have trouble trying to run logstash with it (it is said to be the fastest way to do so).

What I've tryed :

- I installed `rvm` environement (as a side note, the standard install scripts create a new `.bash_profile`, which disable the standard .bashrc script when you're on Ubuntu. This can confuse new users like me... I was wondering for several hours why my 'll' alias won't work !)
- I uncompressed logstash (`jar xvf /logstash-1.1.4-monolithic.jar`) in a new directory
- I've followed the instructions in https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ as `rvm install 1.9.2` (albeit I've also made some try/error/redo manipulations, so I can't remember the exact listing of commands)

Then I tried several commands, but none of them worked :

```
$ ruby logstash.rb
/home/orabig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such     file -- logstash/agent (LoadError)
    from /home/orabig/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from logstash.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

whereas the following line is returning after some seconds :

```
jruby-1.7.0 logstash.rb agent -f ../etc/inout.config -v
```

(the inout.config file is working when invoked with the java commandline as in :)

```
java -jar (...)/logstash-1.1.4-monolithic.jar agent -f ../etc/inout.config -v
```

So I'm basically stuck now, because the more I will try random things, the more I'm afraid to mess up my configuration...

**Update :** On the logstash page (https://github.com/logstash/logstash), it looks like it's working with 1.6.8 ruby version (however it's not clear, and I'm not sure if it makes any difference...)
So I also tried :

```
  $ rvm install 1.6.8
  (...)
  $ rvm use 1.6.8
  $ export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
  $ ruby logstash.rb agent -f ../etc/inout.config -v
  $ jruby-1.6.8 logstash.rb agent -f ../etc/inout.config -v
```

but nothing happens when I run either of the last two lines...

Comment: The best way to get help with logstash is to use the mailing list or IRC channel since that is where the active community and expert users reside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the rvm tool will let you know: You have to be in a login shell to use rvm like that.

So, either run `bash -login` or use rvm to select and run your version of ruby like done in the following:

```
rvm install 1.7.0 # note that 1.7.0 will also work
export JRUBY_OPTS=--1.9
rvm 1.7.0 do bundle install
rvm 1.7.0 do ruby lib/logstash/runner.rb agent -f ../etc/inout.config -v
```

This will tell `rvm` to use jruby-1.7.0 to run your logstash agent.